# Why and when will function definitions are interpreted as declarations in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, frontend

Take a example of this one:

```
var is_android = true;
if (is_android) {
    function foo() {
        alert('I am Android');
    }
} else {
    function foo() {
        alert('I am NOT Android');
    }
}
foo();
```

It will be interpreted as

```
function foo() {
    alert('I am Android');
}
function foo() {
    alert('I am NOT Android');
}
var is_android;

is_android = true;
if (is_android) {

} else {

}
foo();
```

It will alert "I am NOT Android"; Looks like the second foo definition overwrites the first one.

It treats function definitions as declarations, my question is , when will this happen or is this always the case? How to make javascript treat something as a function definition?

Thanks.

Comment: What you're experiencing is colloquially referred to as "hoisting".  Have a look here: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Comment: In your first example, you don't have any valid function declarations. What happens to them depends on your JavaScript engine. Try to `"use strict"` and it will throw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function declarations are always hoisted to the top of the containing scope. You should use an assignment if you want it to be conditional:

```
var is_android = true;
var foo;
if (is_android) {
    foo = function() {
        alert('I am Android');
    }
} else {
    foo = function() {
        alert('I am NOT Android');
    }
}
foo();
```

Comment: bahh I was just typeing this!! good job